# Committing every x rows in table insert

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

I'm writing a huge number of rows (~20 million) to a table from a JDBC connection to a **static** Oracle 12c database. I want to commit every 10,000 rows to prevent rollback and so that I can effectively restart the insert command from the last commit if there is an error.

What is the most efficient (time and resources) way that I can do this using JDBC?

Note that this will be an INSERT INTO SELECT statement from a big underlying table join. As such, cursors will slow down the insert statement considerably - are they truly the best solution here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - how to limit the `select` part to only 10,000 rows? How to identify which rows they are, and/or exclude previously-inserted rows? Why aren't you doing it as a *single* `insert ... select` statement with a single commit at the end - so you wouldn't have to worry about restarting - which would be most efficient (as long as you have enough undo space)? Why would a single batch to 10,000 error, and how would you fix it if it did?

Comment: Due to the number of rows that are being inserted, the insert will take a long time, and unfortunately this needs to be processed in a fairly short window. If there's a problem with the insert and we lose all of the progress we will have to restart from the beginning, plus I don't know whether we will have enough resources (undo space) to process this all in one go. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Kind of, but batching and committing will be slower (if there are no errors) - possibly much slower, depending on how you identify which 10,000 go in each batch. I'm still not sure which bit you need help with though, or how you're thinking of using cursors.

Comment: How to minimise that speed time is what my question is referring to. I'm happy for the insert to be reasonably slow, as long as it's stable and minimises resource consumption: if it turns out that we don't have the resources to process this all in one go, I'll lose the progress of the insert, and will have to redevelop the logic behind the statement.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_data_load.htm to see if any of the alternative strategies there suit you better than your current way (which may  be one of the slowest), though note that it doesnt really matter what driver youre using if youre issuing commands for oracle to insert into one table the results of selecting from another. The driver has nothing to do with flowing data round inside oracle

Comment: A one-shot approach is always recommended, and `INSERT` takes relatively little undo. If you really need to break it up, you could look at `bulk collect` with `limit` + `forall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `insert into ... select ...` in general would be the most efficient (if you system will handle it).

If you really want to split it up you could use a scheme such as

```
while <rows still need inserting>
    insert into x
    select from y where (y is not x) and rownum < 10000;
    commit
```

where `(y is not in x)` is a `not in()` , a `NOT EXISTS()` or other such mechanism on only select rows not yet inserted.